# Sorting a range in a specific worksheet does not work

Tags: excel, vba

I made a code to simply sort a tab on the sheet called "Saisie". It works when "Saisie" is the active sheet. 
But I would like the code to run from another sheet.
Code is:

```
Range("H1:K2001").sort Key1:=Range("H1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
```

Code is written in a module.

I therefore added what I thought necessary to sort when another sheet is active:

I tried:

```
Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Saisie")

sh.Range("H1:K2001").sort Key1:=Range("H1"), Order1:=xlAscending, 
Header:=xlYes
```

Also:

```
With Worksheets("Saisie").Range("H1:K2001")
    .sort Key1:=.Range("H1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
End With
```

For both I have a "1004" error. 
Does anyone know why?

I've made dozens of forums where these solutions seem to works for other users.

Comment: Are there any other workbooks open? `ActiveWorkbook` sometimes causes problems when there are.

Comment: Do you really mean `ActiveWorkbook` and not `ThisWorkbook`? The active one is always the one that has the focus at the moment but `ThisWorkbook` is the workbook your VBA code is running at. This often gets mixed up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your second test:

```
With Worksheets("Saisie").Range("H1:K2001")
    .sort Key1:=.Range("H1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
End With
```

You must use `Worksheets("Saisie").Range("H1")` instead of `.Range("H1")`

Comment: Or in your first test `sh.Range("H1:K2001").sort Key1:=Range("H1")` specify the worksheet `sh` in `Key1:=sh.Range("H1")`.

Answer (score 1):

First to check: Is the worksheet part of the `ActiveWorkbook`? If another workbook is open, the whole code will fail already at the statement `Set sh = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Saisie")`. You could use `ThisWorkbook` instead.

Assuming that this is not your problem: You have to understand on which objects you exactly work. Your first attempt fails because of the SortKey: you write `Key1:=Range("H1")`. `Range`, without qualification, uses the range of the *active* sheet, and this is not what you want (and it will fail).
Try for example

```
sh.Range("H1:K2001").sort Key1:=sh.Range("H1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
```

Your 2nd attempt has a different problem: You use a `Range` in the `with`-clause and write `Key1:=.Range("H1")` as critera. Now, the `.Range("H1")` will be relative to your range in the with-clause. This results in effectively using the range `O1` - again not what you want.

There are many ways to correct this, for example using the worksheet in the with-clause.

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Saisie")
    .Range("H1:K2001").sort Key1:=.Range("H1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
End With
```